# How to use ESC to exit loop

Tags: ruby, loops, exit, rubymine

I was sure this would be a simple problem to search on, but I haven't found anything that works.

I want to exit a loop by hitting <kbd>ESC</kbd>.

```
name = " "
while name > "" do
  puts "(press enter (only) or ESC-key to exit)"; puts {"/n"}
  print "Enter name: "
  name = gets.chomp
end
```

I need to add code that will allow the user to hit the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key to cancel the input.

I use RubyMine, and noticed that pressing <kbd>ESC</kbd> when in the console window sends the cursor to the code window. I'm not sure if this could cause problems with testing any solution.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I'd recommend reading http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints and http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html. We value conciseness over verbosity/fluff, so keeping your question short 'n sweet is great.

Comment: Don't use `puts {"/n"}`. Just. Don't. Using `puts` will accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `gets`, another library takes over. You don't have any control until `gets` returns when the user hits <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

You have to write your own `gets` functionality that exits on escape:

```
require 'io/console'

def mygets()
    char = ''
    name = ''
    while 1 do 
      char = STDIN.getch
      if char.ord == 27
        return '' #depending on you want to do in this case
      end
      if char.ord == 13
        return name
      end
      print char
      name = name + char
    end
end

print "(press enter (only) or ESC-key to exit)\n"
print "Enter name: "

print "\n" + mygets()
```

Comment: `STDIN.getch` will only return a single character at a time so you'll need to aggregate the values until the user hits esc or enter.

Comment: There's no haste. Answers take time. Good answers often take a lot of time. If someone selects a lousy answer it's their problem and others will vote up the good answers, eventually passing the selected poor answer in points.

Comment: Thanks... result from RubyMine console: /Users/***/:6:in `getch': Inappropriate ioctl for device (Errno::ENOTTY)
 from /Users/***/:6:in `<top (required)>'
 from -e:1:in `load'
(press enter (only) or ESC-key to exit)Enter name:  from -e:1:in `<main>'

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Ahh this is a problem of RubyMine and probably another question.

Comment: Also Sublime Text: /Users/*** .rb:7:in `getch': Operation not supported by device (Errno::ENODEV)
 from /Users/***.rb:7:in `<main>'
(press enter (only) or ESC-key to exit)Enter name: [Finished in 2.1s with exit code 1]

Comment: Sorry didn't notice your code was updated above. Basically same error though with Sublime Text and RubyMine: /Users/***.rb:7:in `getch': Operation not supported by device (Errno::ENODEV)
 from /Users/***.rb:7:in `mygets'
 from /Users/***.rb:22:in `<main>'
(press enter (only) or ESC-key to exit)
Enter name: [Finished in 2.3s with exit code 1]

Comment: yes this could be a mac issue. could you try it in the terminal?

Comment: I don't know how exactly ruby programs are run by Sublime or RubyMine. Probably both of them don't constitute proper terminals.